# python guestfs error:Exception AttributeError

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm on `Debian 7.6`. I installed python 2.7 and libguestfs0 and other packages that I need.
This is a sample code that I try to use guestfs, I enter these codes on debian terminal:

```
debian@debian$ python  
>>> import guestfs
>>> g=guestfs.GuestFS (python_return_dict=True)
`Exception AttributeError: "GuestFS instance has no attribute '_o'" in <bound method GuestFS.__del__ of <guestfs.GuestFS instance at 0x203f908>>
ignored 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'python_return_dict'`
```

I searched a lot but I can't find solution for this error.

Thanks

Comment: For starters, the `.GuestFS (python_return_dict=True)` part is wrong since `GuestFS.__init__` is not expecting the argument `python_return_dict`. What happens when it's removed?

Comment: Actually, my real code is like this and it works on Fedora20, but on debian it shows this error. without init it doesn't show anything.